# Is there more spam/trolling on Writing due to lack of moderators?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering, ever since the new CEO replaced the old one, a lot of outraged moderators quit, and as of now, I think there are no Writing moderators. Does this result in more spam and abuse?

Comment: Note - most moderators didn't quit because of the CEO, but because of the unjust firing of a moderator (Monica), and SE's further defensiveness thereafter. A few quit because they disliked the Code of Conduct (aka "the pronouns thing")

Comment: @AprilSalutesMonicaC. Don't forget about the "illegal relicensing" stuff and quite a few other things here and there, like removing the automatic Hot Meta posts from StackOverflow and a lot of stuff that happened over the last years like the ongoing "welcoming" initiatives ;)

Answer (score 7):

The only real increase in "abuse" was the result of one particular user who'd already been a problem before the moderators left, and became even more of a problem afterwards, as there was nobody to stop him and any attempts were met with further abuse. He did eventually get suspended, though.

Other than that, I feel like we've actually had *fewer* spam/troll posts than before. I suspect that the downturn in activity we've had has made us a less attractive target for that sort of thing.

What I *have* noticed is an increase in questions that are low-quality or off-topic. And with no active mods and far fewer high-rep active users, those questions aren't getting closed in time and are receiving (often low-quality) answers, which only encourages further low-quality/off-topic questions, because people know they'll get answered.

It's quite tiring, to be honest with you.

Comment: I still try to clear the queues at least once per day, but there's only so much that does. Do we have any idea how long their suspension is for?

Comment: Until the end of 2020, and I honestly hope they don't come back.

Comment: @WeckarE., who are "they"?

Comment: @RayButterworth "They" are the user referred to in my first paragraph. We're not supposed to name names on Meta, so I didn't.

Comment: @WeckarE., so "they" is newspeak for "he".  I read it as plural and thought I was missing something.

Comment: @RayButterworth or for "she"

Comment: @WeckarE., no, not "she".  It says "***He** did eventually get suspended*", so there was no need to avoid using "he" in the comments.

Comment: @RayButterworth We weren't avoiding it on any conscious level. Their and they is just very natural to me for anyone whose gender I cannot confirm.